# javascript function that opens to full screen when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a javascript function within my HTML document that opens directly to full screen when the webpage has been opened.

I have found a way to go to full screen when a button is toggled here:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

`<html>`

`<head>`

`<meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">`

`<title>True Fullscreen in Processing.js demo</title>`

`<script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="canv">`

```
`//put processing sketch between here` 

int red = 209;
int green = 0;
int blue = 129;

void setup() {
    //size(1000, 480);
}

void draw() {

    //background(200,0,129);
    background(red, green, blue);

}

//and here

// There's probably a better way to do this, but...
// putting this javascript function in the processing sketch lets
// the sketch's values for width and height get updated on resize. 
window.onresize = function() {
    // "canv" is the canvas displaying the Processing program.
    // Make it fill the screen, or the browser window with no sliders:
    var canvElem = document.getElementById("canv");
    var newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var newHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    canvElem.style.position = "fixed";
    canvElem.setAttribute("width", newWidth);
    canvElem.setAttribute("height", newHeight);
    canvElem.style.top = 0 + "px";
    canvElem.style.left = 0 + "px";
    // size() is Processing, everything else 
    // in this function is javascript
    size(newWidth, newHeight);

}
```

`</script>`

`<canvas id="canv">(A Processing sketch should be running right here, but, sadly, your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag. Try Firefox or Safari.)</canvas>`

`<button onclick="toggleFullScreen()">Try it</button>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
`//window.onload = function() { //doesn't work`

//$(function() { //doesn't work

function toggleFullScreen() {

    if ((document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) || // alternative standard method
    (!document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement)) { // current working methods
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    }
}
```

`</script>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

cheers!

Comment: The browser prevents you from going to full screen without user interaction. Imagine how annoying it is if you go to a website and it automatically goes to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Fullscreen API. http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/

It's not widely supported, though. http://caniuse.com/fullscreen